# Unable send email with ajax php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried many times and visited many forums but couldn't find the answer. Please do not post it is similar like some other post. Just try to help me to fix this.

HTML Form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="bookingForm">
<div id="radiobutton">
<input type="radio" name="trip" id="oneway" value="oneway" checked/>&nbsp;Oneway
<input type="radio" name="trip" id="return" value="return"/>&nbsp;Return
</div>
<br/>

From:<input id="boarding" type="text" maxlength="40" class="user_input" size="18" name="boarding" value="Hyderabad"/>
To:<input id="landing" type="text" maxlength="40" class="user_input" size="18" name="landing"/>
<br/><br/><br/>

Onward:<input id="datepick"  name="onward" class="user_input" size="15" />

Return: <input id="datepick2"  name="return" class="user_input" size="15" />
<br/><br/><br/>
Your Name:<input id="pax_name" type="text" name="pax_name"  class="user_input" size="25" maxlength="50"/>
<br/><br/>
Contact number:<input id="pax_contact" type="text" maxlength="14" name="pax_contact" class="user_input" size="25"/>
<br/><br/>
Email:<input id="pax_email" name="pax_email" class="user_input" size="25"/>
<br/><br/>
<center>

<input id="submit" type="button" value="Request" />
```

process.php for sending email:

```
<?php

  $trip=$_POST['trip'];
  $boarding=$_POST['boarding'];
  $landing=$_POST['landing'];
  $onward=$_POST['onward'];
  $return=$_POST['return'];
  $pax_name=$_POST['pax_name'];
  $pax_contact=$_POST['pax_contact'];
  $pax_email=$_POST['pax_email'];

        $to='anvesh@bsbtravels.com,anvifriend@gmail.com';
        $subject='Booking Form Query';
        $body=
              'Name: '.$pax_name."\n".
              'Contact Number: '.$pax_contact."\n".
              'Trip: '.$trip."\n".
              'From: '.$boarding."\n".
              'To: '.$landing."\n".
              'Onward Date: '.$onward."\n".
              'Return Date: '.$return."\n";
        $headers='From: '.$pax_name.'<'.$pax_email.'>';
        mail($to,$subject, $body, $headers)

?>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
          var boarding=$('#boarding').val();
          var landing=$('#landing').val();
          var datepick=$('#datepick').val();
          var datepick2=$('#datepick2').val();
          var pax_name=$('#pax_name').val();
          var pax_contact=$('#pax_contact').val();
          var pax_email=$('#pax_email').val();


    if($('#landing').val().length<3 || $('#boarding').val().length<3 || $('#datepick').val().length<3 || $('#pax_name').val().length<3 || $('#pax_contact').val().length<8 || $('#pax_email').val().length<3){

        $('#bookfail').attr('title','Sending Failed!').text('Please Enter valid information. All fields are required').dialog({buttons:{'Ok':function(){
            $(this).dialog('close');
            }},closeOnEscape:true,draggable:false,resizable:false,modal:true});

    }else{
                var VarData='boarding='+boarding+'&landing='+landing+'&datepick='+datepick+'&datepick2='+datepick2+'&pax_name='+pax_name+'&pax_contact='+pax_contact+'&pax_email='+pax_email;
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'process.php',
                   data:VarData,
           success:function(){
           $('#booksuccess').attr('title','Request sent successfully').text('Your request has been sent. We will be in touch soon').dialog({buttons:{'Ok':function(){   $(this).dialog('close');
            }},closeOnEscape:true,draggable:false,resizable:false,modal:true});
           }
           error:function(){
                alert('Oops request sending failed. Please try again');
           }
        });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the problem/error?

Comment: nothing happens.. when i click the submit button. No dialog box/ no email sent.

Comment: First of all you should check if the ajax request is actually made and there are no javascript errors on page. Try Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: @user1897595 Try pressing F12 in your web browser and looking at the "Console" tab, it should show any JavaScript errors. And the "Network" tab should show all AJAX calls.

Comment: It is not related to your error, but i would use `$.post("process.php", $("#yourForm").serialize());` instead (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Writing less code also minimizes  the chances for errors.

Comment: @user1897595 You should use a tool like firebug (https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) this way you will find the errors in your code very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma after your `success` callback:

```
success:function(){
   ...
}
error:function(){
   ...
}
```

has to be

```
success:function(){
   ...
},// <--
error:function(){
   ...
}
```

Comment: OMG.. what could be the problem. it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting your values in traditional query string format...
Put your values in javascript object and send this object to server by `stringify`ing it...

There are two ways to do this

1] Modify your javascript file a bit like following

Put all your values in an `javascript` object... Like this

```
var VarData= {
    "boarding" : boarding,
    "landing" : landing,
    "datepick": datepick,
    "datepick2": datepick2,
    "pax_name": pax_name,
    "pax_contact": pax_contact,
    "pax_email": pax_email
}
```

and change your `data:varData` line in your `$.ajax()` call to

`data: JSON.stringify(varData)`

After doing this  your `PHP` code will be able to catch the values in `$_POST` array...

Right now you are building query string and there are no indexes in your `$_POST` array like `boarding` and all..

2nd way... Keep your `Javascript` as it is and modify your `PHP` code. Like following

catch your data sent from the javascript code. and use `explode` function to break the string by `&`

```
$temp = explode("&",$_POST['data']);
```

`$temp` will be an array, so you need to traverse through it with loop. And then break each element in `$temp` for `=` sign

like

```
$t=explode("=",$temp[$i]);
```

`$t` will have the value you are looking for and you can use it to send the mails.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Check path to your `process.php` file.. Make sure it is correct. Also are you getting any error on the console?

Comment: yes it is correct, it is in the root folder. console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetParent' of null datepickr.js:290
buildCalendar datepickr.js:290
(anonymous function) datepickr.js:358
(anonymous function)